# Web scraping Issues

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been working on this webscraper and have run into a slight issue.
I got the code to get the following links that are reporting as active from this website

https://www2.cslb.ca.gov/OnlineServices/CheckLicenseII/NameSearch.aspx?NextName=a&NextLicNum

I then parse each active link on the website to pull the data using the links that were gathered.

The problem I am having now is I cant parse the links that were gathered.

I can get it to show me the entire html page of each active link, but when i try to parse I get weird errors, or I just dont know what I am doing.

I mainly just need the text that shows on each link that I gathered.

Still somewhat knew to webscraping and would be delighted if anyone could help me with this situation. I went ahead and posted the code below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


GREEN_URL ="https://www2.cslb.ca.gov/OnlineServices/CheckLicenseII/"

active_website_list = []

def make_soup(url):

    r = requests.get(url)
    html = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    return html

def get_active_licenses(section_url):

    soup = make_soup(section_url)
    tbl = soup.find("table", id="ctl00_LeftColumnMiddle_Table1").find_all("tr")
    for ele in tbl:
        if ele.find('td',{'class': 'Green'}) and hasattr(ele.a, "a"):
            Active_websites = (GREEN_URL + ele.a['href'])
            active_website_list.append(Active_websites)
    return active_website_list

def full_page_content(links):

    parsed_list = []

    for i in active_website_list:
        website = requests.get(i)
        html = BeautifulSoup(website.content)
        parsed_list.append(html)
    return parsed_list










if __name__ == '__main__':

active_license = "https://www2.cslb.ca.gov/OnlineServices/CheckLicenseII/NameSearch.aspx?NextName=a&NextLicNum"

    main_licenses = get_active_licenses(active_license)

    print (full_page_content(active_website_list))
```

Comment: What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: When i run the program, I am just having issues parsing from the links I collected. the program right now collects the correct links and downloads the entire html content. But for some reason I cant parse it. Even If I try using my make_soup module, it does not work. I just need to be able to grab all the text from each link. any help would be awesome.